# Have a bigger fish to fry usage

Tags: idioms

I was wondering about the usage of "have a bigger fish to fry".
Are the sentences **I can't go with you - I have a bigger fish to fry** ***preparing for my tests*** and **I can't go with you - I have a bigger fish to fry *with my homework*** correct or not?

How should I use this structure if I want to say **what is** that important job, to specify it?

Comment: I've never heard the article included there [- it's always **have bigger fish to fry**.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=had+a+bigger+fish+to%2Chad+bigger+fish+to&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chad%20bigger%20fish%20to%3B%2Cc0) Other than that your examples are fine.

Comment: Used this way, "bigger fish to fry" is a put-down of the person asking you to go with them. You're saying that person is not important to you. I'm pretty sure that's not what you want. Just say you have to do your homework and leave the fish fry out of it.

Comment: Maybe turn it round, as in: "I'm preparing for my tests; I've got bigger fish to fry"

Comment: *Bigger fish to fry* implies a policy decision of a sort. You're saying that for the foreseeable future, you will *always* have homework that is more important than going out with the person. It isn't used to say you can't go this one time, but would normally do so.

Comment: Bigger fish to fry means you have more important things to do. It comes without an article. **Sorry, can't go with you, got bigger fish to fry.**

Answer (score 1):

The expression is "bigger fish to fry", no article (fish is plural).

It is a cliché, and it is rather dismissive. It implies that my tasks are more important than yours. It is deliberately ambiguous. The point is that by saying "I have bigger fish to fry" you say that your task is unimportant, without specifying what is more important. In the contexts that you give I wouldn't use the expression at all.

"I can't go with you; I've got homework to do." is clear, polite and unambiguous, whereas "I can't go with you, I've got bigger fish to fry" is clichéd, a little rude, and unclear"

There are situations where the expression can be used: "Don't spend your time learning clichés, there are bigger fish to fry."